# How can I use matlab table (array with named variables) in octave

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-table

In Octave I code:

```
T = table([10;20],{'M';'F'},'VariableNames',{'Age','Gender'},'RowNames',{'P1','P2'})
```

From the example on this website: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html

And get error:

```
't' undefined near line 1 column 1
>> [T, L_X] = table([10;20],{'M';'F'},'VariableNames',{'Age','Gender'},'RowNames',{'P1','P2'})
error: Invalid call to table.  Correct usage is:
-- [T, L_X] = table (X)
```

But when I change to `[T, L_X] = ...`  or to `[T, L_X, L_Y] = ...`  I get the same error. What am I doing wrong and what am I misunderstanding? What should I do to get the example right?  Is this an issue of Matlab/Octave differences?

Comment: Octave does not have a `table` class like MATLAB does.

Comment: One alternative is Andrew Janke’s [octave-tablocious](https://github.com/apjanke/octave-tablicious) package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) *data type* in MATLAB is not yet implemented in Octave. There is a [`table`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Statistical-Functions.html#index-table) *function* in Octave for creating a contingency table, which is what your code is using, and is obviously not what you want.

As an alternative, you may want to check out the [Dataframe package](https://wiki.octave.org/Dataframe_package), which can provide you with similar functionality to a MATLAB `table`.

Comment: thanks @gnovice   how do I  install the dataframe package?  I tried `pkg install -forge dataframe` which did not work...

Comment: @pashute in what way did it "not work"? Did it throw an error? Does the package not show up when you run `pkg list` ? Does it not load when you `pkg load dataframe` ?

Comment: I write `experiment = dataframe('data_test.csv')` and get `unknown ... dataframe` .

Comment: OK I didn't see the `load` part in your comment. Thank you @TasosPapastylianou !

After `pkg install...`  I needed to `pkg load...`  and then everything's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package [Tablicious](https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/tablicious). It, among other things, contains `table` data structure.